# React Get Value og Key from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
[
   {
      "status_code":"200",
      "status_message":"Success!",
      "new_data":[
         {
            "User1":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"ABC"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"XYZ"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "User2":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"bcd"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"bcdx"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Above is my json response from my server. I want to get array key value.
I am doing like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(responseData); // ABOVE GIVEN JSON RESPONSE
obj[0].new_data.map((item, key) => {
                                console.log(item)
                                console.log(key)
                             })

console.log(item) returns array of User1 & User2
```

I want to print User1 & User2 and then go more deep to get values of User1 and User2.
I tried using `console.log(item.key)` but not working

Comment: Share the JSON String as well.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: In console it shows like this {User1: {…}, User2: {…}}

Comment: This should do then `obj[0].new_data[0]`

Comment: Share the data structure you would like to have

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting, please take a look

```js
var a = [
   {
      "status_code":"200",
      "status_message":"Success!",
      "new_data":[
         {
            "User1":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"ABC"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"XYZ"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "User2":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"bcd"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"bcdx"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
];
var data = a[0].new_data[0];
Object.keys(data).forEach(item =>{
  console.log(`your item ${item}`)
  console.log(`Your item data`)
  console.log(data[item])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to say I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve here. But assuming that you want to retrieve data of individual users it will have to go like this.

```
const response = [
   {
      "status_code":"200",
      "status_message":"Success!",
      "new_data":[
         {
            "User1":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"ABC"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"XYZ"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "User2":{
               "info":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"bcd"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"bcdx"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
];
response[0].new_data.map((value, key) => {
    for (var k in value) {
    console.log(value[k]);
  }
})
```